# I want to be able to update a table of grades by updating multiple rows & and columns at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, html, phpmyadmin

THE UPDATE PAGE

This page basically shows the table and under the columns "Assignment 1, 2 & 3" there is an input box for the user to type in a new grade for the students assignment. The input box is coded to show the current values in the database, therefore if the user only updates one record, all will be updated with the current values unless changed by user.

```
<?php 
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }


if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db("kackieco_final",$con);
$query_Recordset1 = "INSERT INTO grades (s_id, f_name, l_name)SELECT s_id, f_name, l_name FROM users WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM grades
WHERE grades.s_id = users.s_id)";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $con) or die(mysql_error());


$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT * FROM grades";
$Recordset2 = mysql_query($query_Recordset2, $con) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2);
$totalRows_Recordset2 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset2);
?>
<form action="admin_post_grades.php" method="post">

<table class="sortable" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="4">
<tr>
<th width="78"><div align="center">Student ID</div></th>  
<th width="78"><div align="center">First Name</div></th>  
<th width="78"><div align="center">Surname</div></th>
<th width="78"><div align="center">Assignment 1</div></th>  
<th width="78"><div align="center">Assignment 2</div></th>
<th width="78"><div align="center">Assignment 3</div></th>
<th width="78"><div align="center">Grade</div></th>
</tr>




<?php do { ?>
  <tr>

    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset2['s_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset2['f_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset2['l_name']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ass1" maxlength="3" size="10" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset2['ass1']; ?>"/> %</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ass2" maxlength="3" size="10" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset2['ass2']; ?>" /> %</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="ass3" maxlength="3" size="10" value="<?php echo $row_Recordset2['ass3']; ?>" /> %</td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset2['grade']; ?>%</td>     
    </tr>

<?php } while ($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2)); ?>
</table>


<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset2);
?>
<input type="hidden" name="s_id" value="<?=$row_Recordset2["s_id"]; ?>" >
<input id="but" type="submit" value="Add"/>
       </form>
```

THE INSERT PAGE

I believe that this is where my problem is, the form on the previous page directs to here so that the data can be inserted/updated. Because the code on the previous page repeats the input field for each row, this means that it needs to be able to update grades for all students.

```
<?php $con = mysql_connect("localhost","*******","*******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  } 

$a1 = $_POST['ass1'];
$a2 = $_POST['ass2'];
$a3 = $_POST['ass3'];
$sid = $_POST['s_id'];

mysql_select_db("kackieco_final",$con);
$q = "UPDATE grades SET ass1='$a1', ass2='$a2', ass3='$a3'";

$r = mysql_query($q, $con) or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_affected_rows($con) == 1) {

    echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    alert("The record has been successfully Added");
    window.back();</script>';
    }   

    else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    alert("The entry could not be added due to a system error");
    window.back()</script>';
    }

mysql_close($con);

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;url=admin_grades.php'>";
?>
```

If you have taken the time to read through this then I thank you and would really appreciate any help you may be able to give. I hope it made sense too!

Answer (score 0):

You could attach jQuery/JavaScript listeners to each of the `input` boxes and mark them with a attribute when they're dirty (user has changed it).  Then add an `OnSubmit` handler to the form so when the page it submitted, it blanks out any inputs that don't have the `isDirty` attribute set.  Finally  on your INSERT page, loop through only fields that are not blank and update them in the database.

(This is untested I just wrote it here so consider it pseudo-code)

```
$('input').change(function() {
  $(this).attr('isDirty', 1);
});

$('form').submit(function() {
  $('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('isDirty') != 1)
    {
       $(this).val('');
    }
  });
  return true;
});
```